# SQL - How to fill in missing values based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| review_id |      old_group       |       new_group       |    desired_result     |
+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|         1 | null                 | null                  | BATCH                 |
|         2 | null                 | null                  | BATCH                 |
|         3 | BATCH                | LEVEL_1               | LEVEL_1               |
|         4 | null                 | null                  | LEVEL_1               |
|         5 | LEVEL_1              | LEVEL_2               | LEVEL_2               |
|         6 | LEVEL_2              | L3                    | LEVEL_3               |
|         7 | null                 | null                  | LEVEL_3               |
|         8 | null                 | null                  | LEVEL_3               |
|         9 | null                 | null                  | LEVEL_3               |
+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

I am working in snowflake and need to write a SQL query that based one new_group and old_group will create a new column filling in the blanks
Each review is assigned a new and old group, I need to combine those values in order to have a separate column that would show specific review group on that review.

I've tried
FIRST_VALUE(new_group IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY review_id ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) but, it does not provide the right result: the last reviews are null as there is no upcoming group and the reviews are a bit shifted.

Comment: Explain how `BATCH` ends up in the desired result column for the first 2 rows.

Comment: The old_group is null for the first reviews, this is how the data is structured. The review group for the first reviews, which do not have the group assigned, should be the first mentioned old_group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, which uses a `LAG()` trick to detect when a new block of `NULL` missing values starts and ends, to be filled in with the non `NULL` value from that group.

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT t.*,
        CASE WHEN old_group IS NOT NULL AND
                  (LAG(old_group) OVER (ORDER BY review_id) IS NULL OR
                   LAG(old_group) OVER (ORDER BY review_id) <> old_group)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS old_flag,
        CASE WHEN new_group IS NOT NULL AND
                  (LAG(new_group) OVER (ORDER BY review_id) IS NULL OR
                   LAG(new_group) OVER (ORDER BY review_id) <> new_group)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_flag
    FROM yourTable t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*, SUM(old_flag) OVER (ORDER BY review_id) AS old_grp,
                SUM(new_flag) OVER (ORDER BY review_id) AS new_grp
    FROM cte1 t
)

SELECT review_id, old_group, new_group,
       COALESCE(MAX(new_group) OVER (PARTITION BY new_grp),
                MAX(CASE WHEN new_grp = 1 THEN old_group END) OVER ()) AS desired_result
FROM cte2
ORDER BY review_id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo